# N transmitters are positioned on a straight road, their position and signal strength is given

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

N transmitters are positioned on a straight road, their position and signal strength is given.
Transmitters can cover distance on either side of the road evenly, i.e. a transmitter with signal
strength of ‘d’ can cover total ‘2d’ length. You need to find all regions which receive signals from
atleast K transmitters.

**directi, medianet  interview questions**

x = [5, 8, 13, 16]
d = [2, 6, 1, 4]

(3,7), (2, 14), (12,14), (12, 20)

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a problem, try to sort input data :-)

Comment: using sort the data and compare them 
time complexity will be o(n^2) they want optimized solution

Answer (score 1):

First,make two arrays for storing X and Y coordinates by doing `x+d` and `x-d` from your input array. One simple way is of `O(n^2)`, find the intervals for each starting point.

Optimize way is to just create a `interval tree` and insert the intervals. Interval tree is a self balancing binary search tree, hence you can get the results in `O(nlogn)`. Here is the link to [Interval](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/) tree.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list (array) of pairs `(StartOfInterval, +1)` and `(EndOfInterval, -1)` for all interval ends.

Sort this list by the first field

`NumberTranmittersHere = 0`

Walk through the list, adding the second field of pair to `NumberTranmittersHere`

Check if current value is at least K

```
        (3+),(7-),(2+),(14-),(12+),(14-),(12+),(20-)
        (2+),(3+),(7-),(12+),(12+),(14-),(14-),(20-)
NTH   0   1    2    1    2    3     2     1     0
```